# Fullcalendar: How to show next two month of next year in timeline view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using Fullcalendar and I need to show all the current year plus the next two month of the next year using a `timeline` view.

If I use the `visibleRange` option in this way:

```
visibleRange: function (currentDate) {
return {
    start: currentDate.year()+'-01-01',
    end: currentDate.year()+1 + '-02-28',
};}
```

The calendar show the correct period but the navigation button 'next' stop working.

I also tried to use the `duration` option instead but I don't know how to set the "start" period.... the calendar start always at current date.

I think there is a solution that not require the writing of a full custom view to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this involves setting the `dateIncrement` value - this tells the next/prev buttons how far to increase/decrease the visible dates by when you customise the view range like this.

Here's an example. N.B. I've used momentJS's built-in functions, rather than string concatenation, to provide a more robust and neater way of setting the visible range. It's probably also a good idea to set the slotDuration to something that won't produce a massive long calendar. I've used a 1 month duration as an example, but obviously you can configure it to whatever you need.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
    defaultView: 'timeline',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeline'
    },
    slotDuration: { months: 1 },
    dateIncrement: { years: 1 },
    visibleRange: function (currentDate) {
        return {
            start: currentDate.clone().startOf('year'),
            end: currentDate.clone().startOf('year').add({ years: 1, months: 2}),
        };
    },
    //...etc
});
```

The dateIncrement setting is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/dateIncrement/